# What is this double lined sans serif script font?

Tags: font-identification

I am tasked (or tasked myself, rather) with continuing the montage of a series of promotional videos for an art exhibition.

Since the person who started the series abruptly left the organization I work for some files are missing, among which the fonts used. I have contacted them, but they replied they no longer have any of the files.

In these videos the following font is used for the title:

[image: 'My Childhood' in unknown font]
<sup>This was isolated from white text over a video screengrab, hence the subpar quality</sup>

I assume the font is free to use.
The videos were made in Resolve, presumably on a Mac, so the font could be part of either. Or neither.
I have tried online font identifying software (*Whatthefont*, *Fontspring Matcherator*, *Identifont*, but they return fonts nowhere near this one), searching for a description of the font, and looking for a list of the fonts that come with Resolve and MacOS for comparison, but no dice.

The *Find My Font (Free)* software finds [Running on Empty](https://www.dafont.com/running-on-empty.font) (seen below), which is close, but not the same, but it did leave me with the feeling that a video effect could have been used, especially since in the video these letters are kind of dancing around.

[image: Find my Font result]

Comment: Video effect or not, the font you found has serif's so cannot be correct, even though tantalisingly "close" - Are you sure it's not custom?

Comment: @mayersdesign Yes, I'm sure, definitely not custom. And can you explain why you think the similar looking font is a serif font? It doesn't look like one to me.

Comment: Sorry I miskeyed and meant the "original" font, plus I misused terminology haha, not a serif, but the "l" has a loop, and the "d"s have (I think they are called "tails") that differentiate it from the font you found in a way a video filter could not have rendered.

Comment: Are you sure the font is not custom? The letters "o" and "d" are shown twice but they look different from each other. Kind of seems like a brush was applied to the stroke to create this text.

Comment: @AndrewH Yes, I've noticed that too, but I can't imagine the person having created this was both that interested in fonts *and* failed to remember it when I asked him after it. It could be they are two similar but distinct fonts superimposed. Or the font was cloned, slightly moved, and an effect was placed on both that independently changes their outlines.